# How to convert int[][] values to double[][] in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, coordinates

So I have `public int[][] Table;` in my first program and would like to convert the values to double so I can make the table more accurate

I'm using
`Table = new[] { new[] { 0, 76 }, new[] { 0, 76 }, new[] { 0, 76 } };`
right now and would like to add decimal to it like 76.54 but it wont let me

I tried doing `public double[][]` but it gives an error cannot convert int to double

Comment: it's unclear question. do you wish to convert int to double?

Comment: or is there any rule to convert int[][] to double?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You may also want to consult [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/5698098). Finally, don't forget to accept an answer (check-mark next to the answer) when it answers your question, so that it doesn't pop up as unanswered anymore.

Comment: be aware: converting from int to double does _not_ make anything more accurate, because you do _not_ gain additional information. worst case, you even lose precision by converting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a *jagged array* of `int` to *jagged array* `double`

```
var result = Table.Select(x => x.Select(y =>(double)y).ToArray()).ToArray()
```

Though it's likely all you need is this, which is *initialising* a *jagged array* of `double`

```
public double[][] Table;

...

Table = new double[][] { new double[] { 0, 76 }, new double[] { 0, 76 }, new double[] { 0, 76 } };
// or
Table = new[] { new [] { 0d, 76d }, new [] { 0d, 76d }, new [] { 0d, 76d } };
```

Comment: GG thanks for the help